# django Model.objects.filter(feildname = 'some_column') vs Model.objects.all().filter(feildname = 'some_column') which one performs better

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to see which of these will perform better

1. `queryset = Model.objects.filter(feildname = 'some_column')`
2. `queryset = Model.objects.all().filter(feildname = 'some_column')`

Answer (score 1):

It becomes the same SQL query underneath, so there is no difference.

Also a database query will take much longer than any Django queryset construction, so if you want to improve speed look at the generated SQL (e.g. with [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

Answer (score 1):

They are the same things if you haven't defined your own manager. We can create our own `BaseManager` and override `all()` method. For ex.:

```
from django.db import models

class BaseManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = BaseManager()
```

And now `SomeModel.objects.all().filter(fieldname='some_column')` - filtering objects with `is_active=True`, in other case `SomeModel.objects.filter(fieldname='some_column')` - filtering all objects, doesn't matter what value has `is_active` field.